# Windows 7 Graphics Driver for an i3-2100

Tags: windows-7, intel-core-i3

I've got an [MSI H67MA-E45](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/H67MA-E45.html) motherboard, with an [Intel i3-2100](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=53422) processor.  When trying to install the graphics driver for Windows 7 (64 bit) I get the error:

```
an error occurred register one or more files
```

The log file shows:

```
[Register COM - 295]
  Registering DLL 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Media SDK\s1\2.0\mfx_mft_h264vd_32.dll'
!     Unable to load DLL (0x7E)
IIF will NOT initiate reboot
Exit code = 0x7E
```

I've tried using the default drivers that came with the pc, using the latest drivers (from Intel & MSI), I've updated the bios...

I'm not sure what mfx_mft_h264vd_32.dll is and why it bombs out.

The driver problem isn't the end of the world, the problem is that when watch the tv through the HD port, the screen is extends about an inch bigger than the screen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wasn't right.  I downloaded the 64 bit drivers (both 8.15.10.2246 & [15.21.12.64.2321](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=eng&dwnldid=19906))

I found [some](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=97283) [links](http://communities.intel.com/message/120325) to other problems with this driver.

I reinstalled with [Windows 7 Home Premium N](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows7/products/compare?T1=tab11) and the driver installed fine.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to install the 32-bit driver DLL into your 64-bit Windows 7.

Go to Intel's HD Graphics driver page for that chipset [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=19929&ProdId=3285&lang=eng), choose the 64-bit driver and give it a shot.